# ask for new challenges

Tags: sentence-construction

I've made a sentence:

> I wouldn't grow in my career if I didn't continuosly ask myself for
>   new challenges.

I tried to say that the fact I found a new challenge everytime I've done with the current one gave me opportunities to grow in my carrer. Does it sound OK?

Comment: Why did you use *ask myself*? The meaning is different from *I found* (in your explanation). It is quite different, but how about "...*task* myself *with* new challenges." Not just found them but also *applied* them to your experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While your sentence makes sense, it might be better if you said:

> I wouldn't advance in my career if I didn't challenge myself.

Or if you're talking that you are currently challenging yourself you could say:

> To advance in my career, I task myself with new challenges.

Switching the sentence around you could say:

> I constantly challenge myself so I can move foward with my career goals.

Comment: Does this sound ok? __I wouldn't advance in my career if I didn't chalange myself every time I've done with the current one__?

Comment: No, you're adding a lot to the sentence, try to keep it short and simple. @D.B

Answer (score 1):

Try: "I am continually looking for new challenges."

Comment: Challenge;  Opportunities; Career; Continuously.  Granted, English spelling is a bear, but four misspellings in one short post is three too many.  Your next challenge, should you choose to accept it, is to figure out how to avoid misspellings.